FT8 not displaying
Why can't I decode the FT8 when using WSJT-X on HF? At first, it decoded one but then, nothing showed up. I didn't change anything. I can still hear the FT8 signals clearly but the software won't decode it (on the "band activity" side, nothing shows up even though I can hear the clear FT8 signal). Why does it work before but doesn't work after? I'm connecting the radio to the computer via an USB.

Are you listening to the correct sideband?  Does the waterfall show any signals?  Have you tried unplugging and plugging back in?  (Yes, that sometimes works.)

sounds like you’re looking for some realtime troubleshooting help, something best found in a forum or reddit or from local hams. This site is intended to serve well researched and specific questions. I do hope you get it! Voting to close.

@webmarc What do you mean by "realtime troubleshooting help"?

try something. Change some thing. Try something. Change some thing. Try something. Change something. rinse and repeat. The answer to “why can’t I decode something” is because you have something misconfigured… and this isn’t a site that’s suited to going back and forth to figure out what’s wrong.

I found out that since I was using a not so well known radio, it didn't show up on the list of radios. So, it is using the microphone instead of the USB port for input. So, it seems like I can't use FT8 after all.

it is possible that your clock is not set to the correct time. FT8 relies on signals starting at a precise time. if the clocks on the transmitter and receiver are not the same, the receiver will not be able to decode the message.
Try a program like NetTime, https://www.timesynctool.com/, on your PC to synchronize your PC's clock.
